# XMPP message carbon: retrieve carbon messages after becoming online?

Tags: jabber, xmpp

Suppose I have 2 devices, laptop and phone, both of which have an XMPP client with message carbon (XEP 0280) feature enabled. The server also has the message carbon feature. If both of my devices are online, I understand that my messages would be synchronized between the two devices. But what about the messages sent or received when my laptop is offline and my phone is online? How to make my laptop retrieve the carbon messages when it gets online later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requires a specification that stores your messages on the server. There are two options:

- [XEP 313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html)
- [XEP 136: Message Archiving](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html)

You should look for a client and server that implement the same spec.